# How can I prove this relation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, linear-algebra

What I want to prove :
$$R_{ijrs}=\partial_r\Gamma_{ijs}-\partial_s\Gamma_{ijr}-\Gamma_{rj}^k\Gamma_{iks}+\Gamma_{sj}^k\Gamma_{ikr}$$
According to Riemann-Christoffel tensor, the covariant composant are given by:
$$R_{ijrs}=g_{jk} R_{ijk}^k    $$ 
We replace the following quantities  $$g_{jk} \partial_r\Gamma_{is}^k$$ 
with:
$$\partial_r (g_{jk}\Gamma_{is}^k) -\Gamma_{is}^k \partial_r g_{jk}$$
So, in the first identity we get the following:
$$R_{ijrs}=\partial_r (g_{jk}\Gamma_{is}^k)-\partial_s (g_{jk}\Gamma_{ir}^k)+\Gamma_{is}^l(\Gamma_{rjl}-\partial_r g_{jl})-\Gamma_{ir}^l(\Gamma_{sjl}-\partial_s g_{jl})$$
And I'm stuck here :'( !!

Comment: Consider making your question more clear. As it stands, it’s not clear what you’re asking.

Comment: I'm asking for a proof, What I add was my try, I want to prove what I asked for :) !! @BobKnighton

Comment: @BobKnighton: it's pretty clear to me what the OP is asking - he's asking for help to prove the equation $R_{ijrs}=\partial_r\Gamma_{ijs}-\partial_s\Gamma_{ijr}-\Gamma_{rj}^k\Gamma_{iks}+\Gamma_{sj}^k\Gamma_{ikr}$ - but got lost in the math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you hint.

Use $R$ and the coordinate vectors of the coordinate system

$$R(\partial_k,\partial_l)\partial_j=\nabla_{\partial_l}(\nabla_{\partial_k}\partial_j)-\nabla_{\partial_k}(\nabla_{\partial_l}\partial_j).$$

Note that

$$\nabla_{\partial_k}(\partial_j)=\Gamma^{m}_{kj}\partial_{m}.$$

Also, you only have to calculate the first term on the right of the equal sign - for the second term you just have to flip the necessary indices.

Then use the metric on $R$ to obtain the desired form if necessary.

Comment: Thank you!! I'll try solving it using your hint, Thanks again

Comment: Also, to get to the final result, I took the inner product of the following equation 

$$R(\partial_k,\partial_l) \partial_j = \sum_{i} R^{i}_{jkl} \partial_{i}$$
with the tangent vector $ \partial_n$

$$\langle R(\partial_k,\partial_l) \partial_j,\partial_{n}\rangle = \sum_i R^{i}_{jkl}g_{in}=R_{jkln}
$$
where $g_{in}=\langle \partial_i,\partial_n \rangle.$ Then I just re-mapped the indices on right side of the question you need to prove.